# Don’t create default lambdaRole when deploying serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-serverless

I am currently using the serverless-iam-roles-per-function plugin to give each of my lambda functions their own IAM roles. But when I deploy it, it seems like it still creates a default lambdaRole that contains all the functions. I did not define iamRoleStatements or VPC in the provider section of the serverless.yml. Am I missing something? I would like to only have roles per function. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Snippet of yml:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: ${env:SLS_STAGE}
  region: ${env:SLS_REGION}
  environment:
    DB_HOSTS: ${env:SLS_DB_HOSTS}
    DB_NAME: ${env:SLS_DB_NAME}
    DB_USERNAME: ${env:SLS_DB_USERNAME}
    DB_PASSWORD: ${env:SLS_DB_PASSWORD}
    TYPE: ${env:SLS_ENV_TYPE}

functions:
  function1:
  package:
    exclude:
      - ./**
    include:
      - ./bin/function_1
  handler: bin/function_1
  vpc: ${self:custom.vpc}
  iamRoleStatements: ${self:custom.iamRoleStatements}
  events:
    - http:
        path: products
        method: get
        private: true
        cors: true
        authorizer: ${self:custom.authorizer.function_1}

custom:
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-00000
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-00001
      - subnet-00002
      - subnet-00003
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
        - ssm:GetParameter
        - ssm:GetParametersByPath
        - ssm:PutParameter
      Resource: "*"
```

Comment: Any chance we could take a look at the serverless.yml? We'd just be guessing without it.

Comment: @JeremyThompson let me provide some snippets